# Momentjs parsing javascript date object inside an async function and format it but can't assign it to the same property

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, momentjs

```
const moment = require('moment');
const db = require("../db/conn");
const runStmtPromisified = require("../utils/runStmtPromisified");

const f = async () => {
    const stmt = `select * from test;`
    const tests = await runStmtPromisified(stmt, [], db);
    tests.forEach(test => {
        test.created_at = moment(test.created_at).format('LLL') // throws error*
        // const momentDate = moment(test.created_at) // **
        // test.created_at = momentDate.format('LLL') // ** This works, why?
    })
    console.log(tests);
}
f()
```

This is the error*

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: May 26, 2020 6:51 PM, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback...
```

I've checked the type of test.created_at, it is an object. And when I log it shows date. So, I am guessing that it's a javascript date object.

Why is it that parsing the variable into another variable and then formatting the new variable and storing it to the original variable works but parsing and formatting and storing directly to the original variable does not work?

Does it have anything to do with the code being inside an async function? or the fact that I am fetching the data from the mysql database?

I tried this which works as well:

```
let jsDateObj = new Date('12/10/1999')

jsDateObj = moment(jsDateObj).format('LLL')
console.log(jsDateObj)
```

Thank you

Comment: Test cases that work are not really useful... Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.